# How to create a filter in power BI to filter rows from a table if the particular column contains certain text?

Tags: database, filter, powerbi, filtering, powerquery

I have a dataset containing a column called `PowerPool`.
It contains values like EAPP, WAPP, NAPP, SAPP, CAPP (based on east, west, north, south and center). However, some rows contain values like WAPP/CAPP, SAPP/CAPP - meaning that a country in a row belongs to multiple power pools.

I want to create a filter in Power BI with EAPP, WAPP, NAPP, SAPP and CAPP as options.
If I select CAPP, then all rows containing CAPP in PowerPool column (i.e., only CAPP, CAPP/EAPP, CAPP/SAPP, etc.) should be selected and filtered in the plot and table.

[image]

In Excel, this is pretty easy. One can simply use the filter option and type in the text. How can I implement it in Power BI dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a column in Power Query or a calculated column with DAX that does this. An example(assuming you only want CAPP) of how to do it with a calculated column would be

```
Contains CAPP = IF(CONTAINSSTRING([Power.Pool],"CAPP")=TRUE(),"CAPP","Not CAPP")
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I also want to have them as filters. And it is not feasible so far to have multiple CAPP, SAPP, etc. as filters in the same level at once.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a slicer on the page with the Power.Pool column? you could include a search box, and select all,  then when a user searches 'EAPP', then can select all.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. In Power Query, split Power.Pool column by `/` into new Rows...
   [image]
   Then your slicer will work.

2. Assuming you have a separate table for the Slicer values, then you can create a new **Measure** with:

```
PowerPool sliced count = 
  var isSliced = CALCULATE(ISFILTERED('YourSlicerTable'[Power.Pool]), ALLSELECTED('YourSlicerTable'))
  var slicedResult = 
    SUMX(
      DISTINCT('YourSlicerTable'[Power.Pool]),
      COUNTROWS(
        FILTER('YourDateTable',CONTAINSSTRING('YourDateTable'[Power.Pool], 'YourSlicerTable'[Power.Pool] ) )
      )
    )
  return IF(isSliced, slicedResult, COUNTROWS('YourDateTable') )
```

Add this measure to your visuals as a Visual Filter and set it to `is not blank`.

Result/demo:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! Splitting by row has one problem with my table. For example, I also have Value column which contains value of a parameter of a country. When the Power.Pool column is split into new rows, then the Values also get multiplied by the number of rows when I want to plot it.

Comment: You can create a measure to handle the duplication of value, or you can try option 2. A third option is breakout the Power.Pool into a separate table and have it as a dimension table. Let me know if you need more details on either of these.

Comment: Thank you for the kind response! Could you please elaborate on what kind of measure can be created to handle the duplication of value?

Comment: Something like: `SUMX( DISTINCT('table'[ID]), CALCULATE(MIN('table'[value])) )` or `SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Value]), [Value])`